# How do I scan pictures or paper with PhoneGap/cordova?

Tags: cordova, phonegap, devextreme

How do I scan pictures or paper with PhoneGap/cordova?
I want to scan the written papers by mobile. But I can not find a plugin for it.

Comment: You cannot scan a picture from cordova plugins but you can capture it using camera plugin.

Comment: @KirankumarDafda hi How do they scan from the camera?

Comment: Youcan capture photo and crop it as per your requirement using javascript crop js functionality.

Comment: It will generate resulted image as per your mobile camera quality.

Comment: @KirankumarDafda  for example is https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.appxy.tinyscan&hl=tr

Comment: I got your point of view, this is not possible with phonegap so you have to capture photo and then you can crop it using jquery crop js like [this](https://fengyuanchen.github.io/cropper/) and then set any other functionality on that image.

Comment: @KirankumarDafda pls help me ? https://stackoverflow.com/q/45754679/8394948