# how to image print in phonegap

Tags: javascript, jquery, cordova, phonegap

I take pictures in the first code. In the other code I want to print it. But the image does not appear on the print screen. Why ?

```
            navigator.camera.getPicture(onSuccess, onError, {
            quality: 100,
            destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.FILE_URL,
            sourceType: Camera.PictureSourceType.CAMERA,
            mediaType: Camera.MediaType.PICTURE,
            saveToPhotoAlbum:true,   //targetWidth:200 ,
            //targetHeight: 200,

            correctOrientation: true,
            allowEdit:true
        });
          function onSuccess(imageData) {
            image=document.getElementById("myImage");
            image.src = imageData;
            path = image.src;
          }

 printt: function () {            

           window.plugin.printer.print(image);


       },
```

Comment: Where is defined the variable "image"? Further, is correct "printt" or has it to be "print"?